# Agile Development and agile.net

Tags: agile

I want to know the difference between Agile development and AgileDotNet development please can you help me or give me a link that can help me please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development) states that:

> Agile software development is a group of software development methods
>   based on iterative and incremental development, where requirements and
>   solutions evolve through collaboration between self-organizing,
>   cross-functional teams. It promotes adaptive planning, evolutionary
>   development and delivery, a time-boxed iterative approach, and
>   encourages rapid and flexible response to change. It is a conceptual
>   framework that promotes foreseen interactions throughout the
>   development cycle.

To my knowledge, there is no such thing as "AgileDotNet development". Someone might have used the phrase to talk about .NET development which uses agile practices?

However, [AgileDotNet](http://www.agiledotnet.com/) is a conference that is run ever year where talks are given about .NET development using Agile methods.

Comment: so if i have a project which it should explain the agileDotNet development, then i want to explain only agile and say that is .NET development which uses agile practices?

Comment: Yes, there is no such thing as agileDotNet development (except for the conference). I interpret agileDotNet development to be ".NET development which uses agile practices".